# Granting access to a file or directory to another user but not all users

Tags: permissions

The question is how to allow one user (but not all!) to access files of another user.

I have a directory `/home/alice/dir` owned by `alice`:

```
$ cd /home/alice
$ ls -l
drwxr-x---  2 alice alice       4096 Feb 10 21:24 dir
```

i.e., owner `alice` and group `alice` have read/execute access.

I want to allow user `bob` access to this directory, but any other user `eve` should not have access.

What I did so far was:

```
$ sudo adduser bob alice
```

and now

```
$ getent group alice
alice:x:1001:bob
```

so now `bob` is in the group `alice`.

However, still `bob` cannot access the directory:

```
$ whoami
bob
$ cd /home/alice
$ pwd
/home/alice
$ ls -l
drwxr-x---  2 alice alice       4096 Feb 10 21:24 dir
$ getent group alice
alice:x:1001:bob
$ cd dir
bash: cd: test: Permission denied
```

What's wrong?

Users were created with

```
sudo adduser alice
sudo adduser bob
sudo adduser eve
```

Comment: You need to have every directory on the path to `dir` with at least execute rights for the group `alice`.

Comment: Yes, `bob` can navigate to the directory where `dir` is, and the `ls -l` output in my question is as seen by `bob` from that directory. But then `cd dir` fails for `bob`, but `su sudo` and `cd dir` works.

Comment: so you want to know why bob can not access a file owned by alice ? bob needs to be a member of the alice group or you need to change the group ownership of the file from alice to bob. I suggest you look at ACL

Comment: I believe that `bob` _is_ a member of `alice` group. Please see the output of `getent` in my question. I've added him to the group with `sudo adduser bob alice`.

Comment: Did you set the whole system up yourself? (or at least the user accounts?)

Comment: Yes, I installed this system myself and I maintain it. I use `sudo adduser alice` to add users.

Comment: bob need access to /all/the/directories/down/to/your/shared/directory and you did not post all the information we need to give you better advice.

Comment: Yes, `bob` has this access. I edited the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

The way of doing it as described in the question is correct.

However, when you update the groups, the permissions of the *current process*, including your shell, are not updated. So in my case `groups` (current shell started by `bob` before the groups were changed) and `groups bob` (current permissions of user `bob`) showed different results:

```
$whoami
bob
$ groups bob # current membership of bob
bob alice
$ groups     # shell run by bob BEFORE the groups changed
bob
$ cd /home/alice/dir
bash: cd: test: Permission denied
```

So I had to close the shell, and even close the tunnel (I was connected to the Ubuntu box via a SSH tunnel) and open a new shell (after I connected to SSH again) and then I saw

```
$whoami
bob
$ groups bob
bob alice
$ groups     # current shell run by bob AFTER the groups changed
bob alice
$ cd /home/alice/dir
$ pwd
/home/alice/dir
```

If `bob` is a service, that service is to be restarted!